# Not able to clone repository through gitpython

Tags: python, git

I am trying to clone a gerrit project onto my local machine through `gitpython` which I installed through the following command.

```
pip install gitpython
```

I have a python script with the following code.

```
#git.py

import git
git.Git().clone("ssh://user@host_ip:port/proj1")
```

This is not giving me the expected result. It gives me the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Git'
```

I can run just `git clone ssh://user@host_ip:port/proj1`, which works perfectly fine and gives me a cloned repository but not through the script.

Also, after installing `gitpython`, the first time I enter `python` command shell, `import git` does not give any error. But, if I do the the same after running the `git.py` script mentioned above, I get the same error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Git'`.

I don't know where I am going wrong and would like some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your file is called `git.py`, it is imported when `import git` is executed. You need to rename it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that code you use was for a different git library. Take a look at their [documentation](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html), i guess something like this should do the trick:

```
import git
git.Repo.clone_from(url, path)
```

I didn't actually tested it but anyway I hope this helps!

Comment: No problem! :) But now im confused a little bit. For this solution to work you also renamed the file right?